# How could I calculate the variance with specific mean

Tags: matlab, mean, variance

When I did my paper researching, I got the painful part to overcome:
I want to calculate the variance matrix with specific mean matrix not the real mean matrix.
Could I implement it with some simple function in Matlab?

Welcome any suggestions!

Comment: Is this a programming question or a stats question? If it's about implementation in MATLAB then let's see some MATLAB code.

Comment: What is a "specific" mean matrix?

Comment: You can see the implementation of `cov` by calling `edit cov` in MATLAB. To subtract an arbitrary vector instead of the mean vector is quite straight-forward to implement.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes no sense. The mean is the mean. And if its not the mean, then, what you are using is not a mean matrix, and your values wont be righ.

Comment: @hbaderts That's I think what he is asking. He wants to calculate the sample variance using a vector for the mean that isn't the sample mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some matrix n by k matrix `X` and 1 by k vector`u`, you could do:

```
X_demeaned = X - ones(n,1) * u;
COV_X      = X_demeaned' * X_demeaned / (n - 1);
```

Typically `u` is the sample mean: `u = mean(X)`, but if your particular problem gives you special knowledge about the true population mean, it would make sense to use that for `u` instead.

Anyway, that's what I think you're asking!